# Removing a key from a dictionary using the value

Tags: python, dictionary, contacts

Can I somehow delete a value from a dictionary using its key?
The function `del_contact` is supposed to delete a `contact` using only the name of the contact, but unfortunately I have the dictionary and the value, but not the key. How can this be solved?

```py
my_contacts = {
    1: {
        "Name": "Tom Jones",
        "Number": "911",
        "Birthday": "22.10.1995",
        "Address": "212 street"
    },
    2: {
        "Name": "Bob Marley",
        "Number": "0800838383",
        "Birthday": "22.10.1991",
        "Address": "31 street"
    }
}


def add_contact():
    user_input = int(input("please enter how many contacts you wanna add: "))
    index = len(my_contacts) + 1
    for _ in range(user_input):
        details = {}
        name = input("Enter the name: ")
        number = input("Enter the number: ")
        birthday = input("Enter the birthday")
        address = input("Enter the address")

        details["Name"] = name
        details["Number"] = number
        details["Birthday"] = birthday
        details["Address"] = address

        my_contacts[index] = details
        index += 1
    print(my_contacts)


def del_contact():
    user_input = input("Please enter the name of the contact you want to delete: ")
    my_contacts.pop(user_input)


add_contact()
print(my_contacts)
```

The problem is that my key of the dictionary is `1` or `Name`, and I want to be able to remove the contact using only the value of `Name`.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Strings are hashable, so it would probably be easier to write the `my_contacts` dictionary such that the dictionary keys are the name of a person.

Comment: If you're going to use sequential ints as the keys for your dict, you're better off using a list -- but as Alexander said, if you want to be able to access contacts by name, using a dict keyed on name would be ideal.

Comment: @Samwise: Given they can delete a contact at a later point, a `list` isn't a great idea (if you store off the user ID, then delete a user that precedes that ID, the stored ID is now off by one).

Comment: Not clear why `my_contacts` is a dict mapping integer keys to dicts, rather than a list of dicts. If you want to find a contact by *name*, though, you'll need a dict that maps names to dicts, something like `{"Tom Jones": {"Name": "Tom Jones", "Number": "911", ...}, ...}`.

Comment: (Otherwise, you'll just have to iterate over the values of the dict, in which case, again, a list of dicts would be just as useful.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically what you can do is iterate of the dict and save only the keys without that user's name.

This code will do the trick:

```
my_contacts = {1: {"Name": "Tom Jones",
                   "Number": "911",
                   "Birthday": "22.10.1995",
                   "Address": "212 street"},
               2: {"Name": "Bob Marley",
                   "Number": "0800838383",
                   "Birthday": "22.10.1991",
                   "Address": "31 street"}
               }
user_input = "Tom Jones"

my_contacts = {key: value for key, value in my_contacts.items() if value["Name"] != user_input}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's two steps here:

1. Finding the key/value pair(s) that match
2. Deleting the keys you found

If you're only deleting a single item (even with multiple matches), always, these can be combined:

```
def del_contact():
    user_input = input("Please enter the name of the contact you want to delete: ")
    for k, v in my_contacts.items():  # Need both key and value, we test key, delete by value
        if v["Name"] == user_input:
            del my_contacts[k]
            break  # Deleted one item, stop now (we'd RuntimeError if iteration continued)
    else:
        # Optionally raise exception or print error indicating name wasn't found
```

If you might delete multiple entries, and must operate in place, you'd split the steps (because it's illegal to continue iterating a `dict` while mutating the set of keys):

```
def del_contact():
    user_input = input("Please enter the name of the contact you want to delete: ")
    to_delete = [k for k, v in my_contacts.items() if v["Name"] == user_input]
    if not to_delete:
        # Optionally raise exception or print error indicating name wasn't found
    for k in to_delete:
        del my_contacts[k]
```

Or if you're okay with replacing the original `dict`, rather than mutating it in place, you can one-line the multi-deletion case as:

```
def del_contact():
    global my_contacts  # Assignment requires explicitly declared use of global
    user_input = input("Please enter the name of the contact you want to delete: ")
    my_contacts = {k: v for k, v in my_contacts.items() if v["Name"] != user_input}  # Flip test, build new dict
    # Detecting no matches is more annoying here (it's basically comparing
    # length before and after), so I'm omitting it
```

Answer (score 0):

Being that the index are used  as keys for the dictionary, the `range` function can be used as follows:

```
def del_contact():
    user_input = input("Please enter the name of the contact you want to delete: ")
    for i in range(1,len(my_contacts)+1):
        if my_contacts[i]['Name'] == user_input:
            del my_contacts[i]
            break
```

If there can be multiple contacts with the same name that need to be deleted, remove the break statement.

But as mentioned in the comments, there is no need to use an index as a key for the dictionaries. A potential bug you'll encounter with that, is if the first entry is deleted whose name is `Tom Jones` the `dict` will have a length of 1 with only one key - 2. Then when you try to add more contacts, when you check the length of the dictionary `index = len(my_contacts) + 1`, since length is 1, index will be 2. Hence `my_contacts[index] = details` will update the contact with a key of 2 or `"Name": "Bob Marley"` instead of adding a new contact.

Answer (score 0):

I think thats what you need, hope that helps:

##### Code:

```py
my_contacts = {1: {"Name": "Tom Jones",
                   "Number": "911",
                   "Birthday": "22.10.1995",
                   "Address": "212 street"},
               2: {"Name": "Bob Marley",
                   "Number": "0800838383",
                   "Birthday": "22.10.1991",
                   "Address": "31 street"}
           }

def add_contact():
    user_input = int(input("please enter how many contacts you wanna add: "))
    index = len(my_contacts) + 1
    for _ in range(user_input):
        details = {}
        name = input("Enter the name: ")
        number = input("Enter the number: ")
        birthday = input("Enter the birthday")
        address = input("Enter the address")
        details["Name"] = name
        details["Number"] = number
        details["Birthday"] = birthday
        details["Address"] = address
        my_contacts[index] = details
        index += 1
    print(my_contacts)

add_contact()

print(my_contacts)
def del_contact():
    user_input = input("Please enter the name of the contact you want to delete: ")
    values = [key for key in my_contacts.keys() if user_input in my_contacts[key].values()]
    for value in values:
        my_contacts.pop(value)
del_contact()
print(my_contacts)
```

##### Input:

```
{1: {'Name': 'Tom Jones', 'Number': '911', 'Birthday': '22.10.1995', 'Address': '212 street'}, 2: {'Name': 'Bob Marley', 'Number': '0800838383', 'Birthday': '22.10.1991', 'Address': '31 street'}, 3: {'Name': 'myname', 'Number': '1233455', 'Birthday': '12-12-22', 'Address': 'blabla street'}}
```

```
Please enter the name of the contact you want to delete: Bob Marley
```

##### Output:

```
{1: {'Name': 'Tom Jones', 'Number': '911', 'Birthday': '22.10.1995', 'Address': '212 street'}, 3: {'Name': 'myname', 'Number': '1233455', 'Birthday': '12-12-22', 'Address': 'blabla street'}}
```